# Parsing JSON-like file type to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have lots of files with an unusual file extension.

I need to read the files using JavaScript and convert their contents to JSON or regular JavaScript objects.

Is this even possible?

I have some hope, because the files are already structured very similar to JSON:

```
// file.unusualFileType

Page: {
  id: P001
  Title: "Page Title"
  URL: "/home"
  Elements: {
    Button: {
      Text: "Click me"
      Action: SAVE
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Håken Lid kindly provided a solution for my particular use case. Out of curiosity I would still be interested in how to read any file as a string with JavaScript and how one could possible parse such a string.

Comment: Looks like it might be YAML

Comment: An awful lot of replaces / regex is needed in order to get your data to look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/w0jb96vp/

Comment: Can you say what the unusual file type is? Someone may have a package to convert it to JSON.

Comment: I would be interested in a solution that works for all file types

Answer (score 1):

It would be valid yaml if you strip out the curly brackets. You can use [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) to parse the sample data, so maybe it works with the rest of your files too?

```js
const rawData = `
Page: {
  id: P001
  Title: "Page Title"
  URL: "/home"
  Elements: {
    Button: {
      Text: "Click me"
      Action: SAVE
    }
  }
}`
const yamlData = rawData.replace(/[{}]/g, '')
console.log(jsyaml.load(yamlData))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-yaml/3.13.1/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your help! If you have suggestion on where to start researching a solution that: 1) reads the file with JavaScript instead of copy/pasting the file contents to a .js file and wrapping them in a string and 2) also works for a non-yaml like file structure, let me know :)

Comment: 1) If it's a node app, use fs.readFile(), if it's a browser app, [there are several options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications). 2) That's a hard problem. It's vastly better to just stick with standard config formats such as json or yaml.

Comment: I add the js file  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-yaml/3.13.1/js-yaml.min.js"></script>

and try to do the following
 ```<script >
  var doc = jsyaml.parse('greeting: hello\nname: world');
  console.log('docdocdocdoc');
  console.log(doc);
</script>```
I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsyaml is not defined`